# How to horizontally aligning label, input and i elements within a div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a text input with bootstrap search icon. However the label, input element and search icon all appear in different rows. I am trying this in Firefox latest version.

[`Here`](https://jsfiddle.net/fs29ar8p/1/) is the JSFiddle link. Below is the same code.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="div1" class="container row">
  <div id="countryDiv" class="right-inner-addon form-group col-xs-4">
    <label style="display: inline-block" for="billingCountryDiv">Country:</label>
    <input id="countryId" type="text" class="form-control" style="display: inline-block"/>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="display: inline-block"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There multiple things you need to take care of, though I have fixed your issue.

**Edit:**

1. You should add `<form>` with `class="form-inline"`
2. Remove inline css. Use proper classes. [See this example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_inline&stacked=h)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="filterDiv2" class="container row">
     <div id="countryDiv" class="right-inner-addon form-group col-xs-8">
      <label style="display: inline-block" for="billingCountryDiv">Country:</label>
      <input id="countryId" type="text" class="form-control" style="display: inline-block;width: auto;"/>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="display: inline-block"></i>
     </div>
          </div>
```